# Allow one occurrence in regular expression

Tags: regex

I would like to restrict my regex with some characters like < > @ # and allow only one occurrence of | character. So far I didn't have success.

```
^([^<>@#]+[|]?)$
```

Can't figure it out how to restrict my regex to only one occurrence of | char.

Comment: Does pipe have to occur exactly once, or could it also not occur at all?

Comment: It can occur only once or none at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!(?:[^|]*\|){2})[^<>@#]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KSrVwj/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!(?:[^|]*\|){2})`  - there cannot be 2 occurrences of 0+ chars other than `|` and then `|`
- `[^<>@#]+` - 1 or more chars other than `<`, `>`, `@`, `#`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks man! This is working solution. I will mark this as right answer.

Comment: This expression will match a string that meets the restriction requirement (`^[^<>@#]+$`, one or more chars other than those in the negated character class) having only `|`  char *anywhere* in the string. So, `|`, `d`, `|d`, `d|` are all [valid matches](https://regex101.com/r/KSrVwj/2). I added `\n` in the demo because the test is performed against a multiline string.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello guys, negative lookahead are still not compatible with iOS and Safari in 2021 ‍♀️
Do you have a working solution not using this? Thanks!

Comment: @LoïcV Lookaheads are compatible with Safari. Lookbehinds are not.